# Play2 : compilation error with implicit value for parameter flash

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I begin in Play 2 and Scala, and I create a very simple login form. All works perfectly until I use flash to store the login result. All I obtained is  the error :

`/home/denis/dev/workspace/atabank/app/views/login.scala.html:5: could not find implicit value for parameter flash: play.api.mvc.Flash`

According the Play documentation, I put in my controllers `implicit request => ...`, I use `Ok(...).flashing("error" -> "wrong password")`, but the error still here...

Here my code :

Login controller :

```
package controllers

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{ mapping, nonEmptyText }
import play.api.mvc.{ Action, Controller, Flash }

object Login extends Controller {

def login = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.login())
}

def authenticate() = Action { implicit request =>
    {
    val form = loginForm.bindFromRequest()

    form.fold(
        hasErrors = {
        form =>
            Redirect(routes.Login.authenticate()).flashing("error" -> "Connection error")
        },
        success = {
        userInfo =>
            if ("123456".equals(userInfo.password))
                Redirect(routes.Home.show(userInfo.login)).flashing("success" -> "Successfully connected")
            else
                Redirect(routes.Login.login()).flashing("error" -> "Wrong password")

        })
    }
}

val loginForm: Form[LoginInfo] = Form {
    mapping(
        "login" -> nonEmptyText,
        "password" -> nonEmptyText)(LoginInfo.apply)(LoginInfo.unapply)
    }

}

case class LoginInfo(login: String, password: String)
```

login.scala.html :

```
@()(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
@import helper._
@import controllers.Login._

@main("Login") {

    <div class="container">

        @helper.form(action = routes.Login.authenticate(), 'role -> "form", 'class -> "form-signin") {
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <input type="email" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        }    
    </div>

}
```

main.scala.html :

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <!-- CSS, JS -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @if(flash.get("success").isDefined) {
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    @flash.get("success")
                </div>
            }
            @if(flash.get("error").isDefined){
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    @flash.get("error")
                </div>
            }
            @content
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

home controller :

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc.{ Action, Controller }
import play.api.mvc.Flash

object Home extends Controller {

    def show(username: String) = Action { implicit request =>
        Ok(views.html.home(username))
    }

}
```

home.scala.html :

```
@(username: String)(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)

@main("Home page") {
    <h1>Welcome Mister @username</h1>
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found another cause of this error : There must be no space just after the closing parenthesis in template :

`@() (implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)` -> Error

`@()(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)` -> No error !

Answer (score 0):

The implicit you've got in your controller is a RequestHeader, not a Flash. You can retrieve the flash from the request by doing something like that in your view :

```
@request.flash.get("success")
```

It should be an Option, so you should map on it in order to process the value if it is here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm getting the solution.
If I add `@request.flash.get("success")` in my form, I got an error : `not found: value request`.
After some trial and error, I resolved my problem : I have to delete in my form `@import controllers.Login._` and in my login controller, replace `import play.api.mvc.{ Action, Controller, Flash }` by `import play.api.mvc.{ Action, Controller }`. After deleted these two imports, the project compiles and works.

I'm not expert in Scala, but I suppose that was I imported implicitly two times flash, so the compiler could not choose.

Thanks.